# How to access the hardware in QNX?

Tags: c++, operating-system, qnx

I installed QNX on the machine. The question is, the embedded system must also have access to the hardware, port management, and so on. How is this implemented in QNX? In what direction to study? So far I've found this the organization of files, directories, users, groups, etc. Or I do not understand the operating principle of the system

Comment: Probably useful: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.pci_server/topic/server.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NOTE: I PUT A LINK ON CODE SAMPLES at THE BOTTOM.

Ill try to explain it in terms of difference between `Linux and QNX`.

`QNX` is a `RTOS` and its `kernel` can be referred as `Neutrino Kernel`. `Kernel` is just a bare bones which interacts with `H/W` and it is the core of any `operating system`, But `OS` consists of `application software` and `Kernel` which works in `unison` to achieve the purpose of a `computer system`.

`Linux` on its own is just a `Kernel`, the `GNU/Linux` is a complete `OS`.

`Linux` is based on `monolithic architecture` whereas QNX is `Micro Kernel`.

`Monolithic kernel:` all the `OS service` run along with the `kernel main thread` thus residing in the same `memory`. `Monolithic kernels` are easier to implement but a `bug` in some part like the `driver` can bring down the total system.

MORE RANT:

`QNX` is a complete `microkernel` based on `realtime OS`, vs `Linux` which is a `monolithic kernel`. `QNX` can run on many `Embedded platforms`, such as on `mini computers` in cars which have `satnav` or `music controls`.(Jeep Cherokee), `SCADA systems`. The application building `framework` is much different than `X11`, or `Wayland` you get on `Linux`. As shown in `QNX GUI` it is much closer to to the bone and metal.

Example: In `Linux` if you want to draw a circle on the screen, this will go through many layers of abstraction like the `X11`, in `QNX` things take a more direct route which makes it faster on a small chip, this results in loosing most of the `networky` stuff which `X11` makes possible on to `Linux`.

`QNX` is somewhat out of the box, supported `framework` for making `embedded systems`, vs `GNU/LINUX` is a bit more opposite of this.

`Real Time` side of things is about both `timely responses` and `accuracy of the response`.

Look [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-qnx-operating-system/184402409) to understand `QNX` and different parts that you need for `coding`.

`QNX` Sample Code can be found [here](http://www.qnx.com/download/feature.html?programid=26215).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for QNX SDP 7 is at http://www.qnx.com/download/group.html?programid=29184 - you'll need to log in to access it (create an account if you don't have one already).

The QNX Neutrino System Architecture guide is a must read.

By and large, hardware access will be needed for system startup (see Building Embedded Systems) and processes providing system services (Writing a Resource Manager). Primarily you'll be looking at having sufficient privilege to access ports, attach interrupt handlers, and map hardware resources into the address space of your program, then creating initialization routines,  interrupt handlers (QNX Neutrino RTOS Programmers Guide), and various forms of event responders that operate in threads within resource manager processes when unblocked by interrupt handlers. The QNX Neutrino Cookbook gives some examples. Look for functions like mmap* in* out* shm* in the library reference and when searching for examples.

But, study and really learn the System Architecture first, it will be hard to find your way around the rest of the documentation and make sense of it without understanding the architecture and the associated terminology.

Have fun!